# Should I be worried about cassandra hints in case of dc downtime?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I will soon be expanding to 2 dc's from 1 and thus I am a little worried  about what happens when while using LOCAL_QUORUM I have one of the dc's that is down.

Lets say I have 2 dc's: dc1 and dc2. Keyspace A will be replicated along d1 and d2 both.

Now how large will hints be a problem in case where I am unable to replicate my writes to dc2 when using local quorum to write in dc1. I know that the writes will be acknowledged as a success since using local quorum but since the data needs to be replicated so that the same can be read in dc2 for analytical purposes, would the build up of cassandra hints be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on amount of writes, and how you want to recover from downtime, and how big downtime could be:

- Cassandra sends writes to all nodes anyway - `LOCAL_*` just says that acknowledgement should come from local DC
- If another DC is down, hints are written to disk, and replayed after DC is up
- If DC will be down for longer than `max_hint_window_in_ms`, then you'll need to perform repair anyway, so replaying hints will just add an additional load to servers

If you expect that DC will be always down for longer period of time, you may disable writing of hints for another DC via `hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters` setting - but you'll need to perform repair after DC is back.

P.S. I see the `datastax` tag - does this mean that you're using DSE? If yes, what version? Because in DSE 6.x, NodeSync can catch up with missing data.